# Hard to shift manual + Vibrations

Tags: shifting, vibration, accident

2011 Nissan Xtrail, 2.0 Diesel, 170.000km, 6 Speed manual

I've rear ended someone 3 weeks ago and I am having some issues.

The first visible damage was the intercooler, which was bent and was having a boost leak in one of the joints. Repaired the joint and now it's ok.

But in time, these issues started to pop-up, maybe related to the accident:

- Hard to shift. The gearbox worked smoothly, until recently after the accident. Now when I put it in gear, I can feel something in the way, doesnt go in smoothly. No grinding though. Worse when AC is ON.
- Gearshift jerks when engaged in first and moving the car from standstill. It wasnt noticeable before, but now i can see and hear, a little, when the shift moves back. Doesnt snap out of gear though.
- If I keep my hand on the shifter and press gently on it, when engaged in first and the car is moving, I can feel the engine vibrations.
- Engine vibration in the clutch pedal, when car is on the move.
- Car vibrates at around 2000rpm under acceleration. I can feel some side to side vibrations. Maybe related to worn rear diff bushings, will have those replaced. Worse when AC is on
- Knocking noise on timing side, upper side. Maybe i was there before and I am just hearing it now. Maybe I'm just hearing it after my windhield was changed at around the same time of the accident and not sealed properly.

Checked engine mounts, transmission mount, lower and they look good.

Gearshift linkage looks ok.

No oil, coolant leak etc.

Didnt have the time to take it to a mechanic, drove it like this for about 1500km. Will take it next week, but these issues are driving me nuts.

Anyone have any idea on what can cause this? 
Are the issues related to the accident or is the car crapping out on me?

Thanks.

P.S. Car was involved in another similar but worse accident years ago, the reinforced support behind the front bumper was bent. But I dont think I did any more damage to it.

Comment: Any investigations as to the condition of the clutch and/or DMF? I wouldn't have said it was directly accident related but 170kkm might be around the time a hard worked clutch is giving up.. Cable operated clutch - is the cable in good condition? Hydraulic clutch - fluid level ok/any visible leaks?

Comment: @CaiusJard Clutch seems ok, but will let the mechanic check it and the flywheel. No brake fluid loss from the clutch pipes.